# Bridge Network Virtualbox is not working

Tags: networking, kali-linux, virtualbox

I installed virtualbox on my windows 10 and I run Kali Linux. When I first install it I set bridge adapter instead of NAT and it is working perfectly until I turn off my pc.

After that it is still on bridge network but there is no internet inside the virtualbox (Kali linux). I tried to reinstall it yesterday and it worked again. Today I woke up started the virtual box and I have the same issue.

I use bridge adapter, Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9560 160MHz. NAT is working perfectly but I don't need it.

Comment: please also mention Kali linux version

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. When I change my MAC address in Kali Linux, it doesn't recognize it on the next reboot.

```
crontab -e
```

in this I put:

```
@reboot macchanger -r eth0
```

and I removed it and now is working perfectly.